# apache aliasmatch return 404

Tags: apache, wamp, alias

I have the following line in my httpd.conf file:

```
AliasMatch ^/myProject/src/foobar/(?:.*)$ /myProject/src/foobar/index.html
```

What I'd like to happen is for any URL that matches the pattern of `http://localhost/myProject/src/foobar/(.*)$` to redirect to the index.html file I have hanging out in at `http://localhost/myProject/src/foobar/`.  Instead, I get a 404 when I try to access any file inside the `foobar` folder.  What gives?

Comment: Do you have a virtual host setup? Have you give Apache permission to access `/myProject/src/foobar`

Comment: I ended up figuring it out - turns out I needed some Directory permissions as well.  All is well now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Syntax: AliasMatch regex `file-path|directory-path`**

examples:
`AliasMatch ^/one c:/wamp/www/index.php` [windows]
`AliasMatch ^/icons(.*) /usr/local/apache/icons$1` [linux]